# Summing of numbers in a file using shell script

Tags: shell

I need the below numbers present in a file named "**folder1**" to be summed up in the group by fashion using a shell script.

```
A:10
A:12
A:15
B:10
B:10
```

Output:

```
A = 37
B = 20
```

Comment: A  and B can be anything

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _anything_? For instance, can A and B also a space or a colon or a carriage return character (all of them could be considered an instance of _anything_)? Is A and B always a single character? What syntax do the numbers obey? I.e. are they always unsigned integers, and if so, what's their maximum possible value? Can they contain a leading zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `awk`

```
awk -F: '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in a) print i":"a[i]}' file
```

#### Using `Perl`:

```
perl -F: -nE '
    BEGIN{ my $h = {}; }
    $h->{$F[0]}+=$F[1];
    END{foreach my $i (keys %$h) { say "$i:$h->{$i}" }}
' file
```

#### Output:

```
B:20
A:37
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `awk` is likely the way to go:

```
awk -F: '{
    sum[$1] += $2  # Accumulate sums for each group identified by $1
} END {
    for (id in sum) {
        print id " = " sum[id]  # Print the result for each group
    }
}' folder1
```

You could also use `cat` ,`cut`, `sort` to achieve your desired result:

```
cat folder1 | cut -d: -f1,2 | sort | {
    prev_id=""
    sum=0
    while IFS=: read -r id value; do
        if [[ $id != $prev_id && $prev_id != "" ]]; then
            echo "$prev_id = $sum"
            sum=0  # Reset sum for new id
        fi
        sum=$(($sum + $value))  # Accumulate sum
        prev_id=$id  # Remember last id
    done
    # Print the last id and sum if we've exited the loop
    if [[ $prev_id != "" ]]; then
        echo "$prev_id = $sum"
    fi
}
```

***Note:** The above assumes that you don't have access to associative arrays due to the version of your shell.*

**Output:**

```
A = 37
B = 20
```